# How to stop next request execution in postman on a condition when a variable does not contain any value?

Tags: postman

I have a test scenario in postman where I have to stop the execution of next request if an envrionment variable value is null. Below is the piece of code and collection description:

Collection details: I have two request in a collection test1 & test2. If in below scenario variable "document" has value then I want request "test2" to be executed otherwise request "test1" should keep on executing as per the data being passed from the csv sheet.

```
pm.test("Verify the the: " + data.value + " exist in " + data.source, function() {
    _.each(pm.response.json(), (arrItem) => {
        pm.expect(arrItem.id).to.be.equal(data.value);
        pm.expect(arrItem.source).to.be.equal(data.source);
        findDocument(arrItem);
    })
})


function findDocument(arr) {

    arr.links.forEach(a => {
        if (a.id.indexOf('A90') > 0) {    
            pm.environment.set('document', a.id)        
        } else
            postman.setNextRequest(null)    
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the response, please?

Comment: Sorry, response is huge. But my query is how to skip the next request based on the conditional behavior or value exist.

Comment: Add a reduced version of it, you don't need to post the whole thing. It was more to see what you're trying to do with that code as I suspect it's probably more than what's needed to do that. I would also use `pm.iterationData.get('value')` over what you have.